# Black Screen with cursor before log in

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-desktop

I have tried all the possible solutions to solve it given in the internet. But my problem does not solved.
So I want to reset my pc. If so is my pc get back to normal state. Previously I have resetted my pc for another problem. Is my resetting option works again. My friends said that reset options works only once... 
Can anybody suggest me what to do??

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be that Windows thinks you have a new monitor that does not exist.

The most common solution that seems to have worked for many people (did not actually work for me, but worth a try):  Wait long enough so the mouse cursor to appear when you move the mouse.  (blank screen with a white mouse cursor) Then press the Ctrl and enter your login password.  Wait until login competed then press Win+P keys, down arrow keys twice, and enter to extend display. (this spans your monitors onto one display)

The solution that worked for me was to unplug all monitors, reboot (hard reset, holding down power button), then plug in just one monitor. (may need to reboot again)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by pressing

1. Press Ctrl+alt+Esc.
2. Task Manager Window Appears,Then Click File
   Option above,then Select Run New Task from the options that are
   listed.

3.Create New Task Window appears and type "explorer" and press   Ok. Screen Appears and Restart your laptop again .

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following solution. It works perfectly. 1. Press Ctrl+alt+del 2. Select Task manager 3. Select File option above 4. Click Run new task 5. Type "explorer.exe" and press Enter You'll screen appears again!!